# JAX-RS Swagger Snake case

Tags: java, jax-rs, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I am the swagger generator for JAX-RS:

```
<dependency>
       <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
       <artifactId>swagger-jaxrs</artifactId>
       <version>1.5.12</version>
</dependency>
```

And I would like to use snake cases for my swagger.json. I know it is possible to use `io.swagger.annotations.ApiModelProperty`, but that would mean I have to do it for every property. My preference is to configure this from a central point. The best that I could find is:

```
Json.mapper().setPropertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategy.SNAKE_CASE);
```

This however creates a swagger.json, which swagger-ui can't handle, because this will convert the swaggers `basePath` to `base_path`. I can not find proper documentation on this part and this looks like such a trivial thing to do. Does anyone know how to handle this properly?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the ModelConverter, which seems to be the appropriate way. My implementation is based on: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/blob/master/modules/swagger-core/src/test/java/io/swagger/model/override/SnakeCaseConverterTest.java